# Weird crash "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>" about declare-styleable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

To implement theming, I defined my custom style attributes to avoid overriding system styles

**themes.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="MyThemeBase">
    <attr name="myTextColorHighlight" format="reference|color"/>
</declare-styleable>

<style name="MyThemeBase" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
</style>

<style name="MY.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Orange" parent="SCThemeBase">
    <item name="myTextColorHighlight">@color/textcolor_highlight_orange</item>
</style>

<style name="MY.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Blue" parent="SCThemeBase">
    <item name="myTextColorHighlight">@color/textcolor_highlight_blue</item>
</style>
```

I also defined custom TextAppearance
**styles.xml**

```
<style name="My.TextAppearance.Medium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <!-- this line caused crash -->
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/myTextColorHighlight</item>

    <!-- this worked -->
    <!--<item name="android:textColor">@color/textcolor_highlight_orange</item>-->
</style>
```

In the layout xmls, some TextViews referenced above MY.TextAppearance.Medium style, everything looked so far so good. But I got crash while layouting one TextView which was in a ListView, the stacktrace was

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.xxx.yyy.MyListAdatper.getView(MyListAdatper.java:46)
```

The most weird was other TextViews in same style were good

I've no idea why I ran into this. With some debugging I just found that it worked only if I used direct color instead of attr reference (please check out comment in above styles.xml) in definition of My.TextAppearance.Medium.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: `?attr/myTextColorHighlight` shouldn't this be `?attr/textColorHighlight`?

Comment: @Kenny, I declared myTextColorHighlight

Comment: Ah, sorry. My apologies.

Comment: @fifth I have added an answer to this question, even if it's a few years later :) It's actually a common issue, so, if you find the answer right, it might be useful for other people if it gets accepted. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your approach. What you have defined is a styleable, that is, a custom attribute that you would like to be able to assign different values to.

Instead, what you want is an attribute reference, which is a constant id that can be assigned different values depending on the theme.

For that, instead of:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyThemeBase">
    <attr name="myTextColorHighlight" format="reference|color"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Just put:

```
   <attr name="myTextColorHighlight" format="reference|color"/>
```

That is, you just need to remove the "declare-styleable" wrapper. That should make it work without problems.